# Webpack, Object.assign and React-Toolbox trouble

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-style-loader

So this is my webpack config file:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

  module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './static/js/index',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/bundles/',
    },
    resolve: {
      modulesDirectories: ['../node_modules', 'bower_components'],
      extensions: ['', '.scss', '.css', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['react-hot',
            'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=react,plugins[]=transform-object-assign'],
        }, {
          test: /(\.scss | \.css)$/,
          loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style',
            'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass')
        }
      ],
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer],
    sassLoader: {
      data: '@import "theme/_config.scss";',
      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './static')]
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('react-toolbox.css', { allChunks: true }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if errors are present
      new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    ],
  }
```

And here are the error messages I'm receiving:

```
ERROR in ./static/js/reducers/account.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/react_boiler/static/js/reducers/account.js: Unexpected token (9:14)
   7 |     case 'GET':
   8 |       return {
>  9 |         Object.assign({}, state, {
     |               ^
  10 |           accountId: action.value
  11 |         })
  12 |       }
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:89:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:83:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:739:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:491:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:18:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:277:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:257:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:188:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:165:19)
 @ ./static/js/reducers/index.js 15:15-35

ERROR in ../~/react-toolbox/lib/input/theme.scss
Module parse failed: /Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/input/theme.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/Evita/Dev/ev_PrecisDigitalTools/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
 @ ../~/react-toolbox/lib/input/index.js 18:13-36
```

Now, I'm aware that Object.assign isn't available out of the box, so like you can see I've tried adding the plugin 'babel-transform-object-assign' (as mentioned here: https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/45), and I've tried requiring it from core-js (https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#commonjs), and from babel-core, and as a 'runtime' option etc. Simply – no go.
Postcss apparently caused problems, but I've already downgraded that.

I haven't really begun trying to fix the sass loader problem, thinking that I'd start with that after I'd solved the Object.assign issue, although I've been at it since the past 5 hours and I'm literally getting nowhere. So I've added both the error messages hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I suspect I've confused old syntax with new etc, but I really can't figure this one out... help??

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like this:

```
return {
    Object.assign({}, state, {
        accountId: action.value
    })
}
```

I think this will be right:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    accountId: action.value
})
```